# React Hooks Vs React-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

After introducing hooks to `Reactjs`, Are they a good replacement for global store management like `Redux` or not? It's about their performance to react.

I have used `Redux` and `redux-saga` in my recent projects but after introducing hooks I'm interested to replace them.

Comment: In my opinion, there’s no need to choose one over the other. This article explains how you should mix both or when to choose one over another https://medium.com/javascript-scene/do-react-hooks-replace-redux-210bab340672

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One thing you need to understand is that hooks aren't meant to replace redux stores nor are they used for global store management. You use hooks so as to make the implementation of the components easier(replacing class components with functional components ), the components will themselves still rely on some data that is stored in the redux store. You use redux so that multiple components in your app can use the same redux store.

For example, say you have 2 components a `<Hello>` that says "Hello user_name" and a `<Welcome>` that says "Welcome user_name". Now both these components require the same data which is user_name. If we use a redux store we can store the data in a single location and use it throughout the app by passing it as a prop. Now we can implement the `<Welcome>` and the `<Hello>` with hooks instead of class components but the data that they need should come from a global store.

Comment: cant u create a globale state manager with hook? without using redux!

Comment: @adel Hmm with useState() or something ? maybe but still you would have to manually make sure your components all rerender when one of the props changes... Its possible, but difficult to maintain, plus that is what redux does automatically and it should be more efficient. Why waste time on something when there is a really good library for it?

Comment: you right, but I see the global store that implemented with `react hooks`
my concern is about **performance** are they equal?

Comment: Like I said you can implement a global store with hooks. Is the performance of using hooks to maintain a global state better? Honestly, I don't know. Although I've seen a few articles on how to implement a global store with hooks, I've never actually seen any reason to why this is better than a redux store. So my opinion is unless you are required to do so don't go for it. I say this because of the maintenance overheads you might face later on. But If you want to try it here's something you can read https://itnext.io/replace-redux-state-with-react-hooks-and-context-7906e0fd5521.

Comment: Depending on the extent of "global state" you need, the react hooks useContext and useReducer can be used instead of Redux